# ViewModel Class with List

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

hi I have created a ViewModel Class like this

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public List<ClassC> c { get; set; }
    public List<ClassD> d { get; set; }
}
public class ClassC
{
    public string A1 { get; set; }
    public string B1 { get; set; }
}
public class ClassD
{
    public string A1 { get; set; }
    public string B1 { get; set; }
}
```

then i have adding values like this in MainClass

```
public ClassA MainClass()
    {
        ClassA CA = new ClassA();
        CA.A = "abcd";
        CA.B = "efgh";

        ClassC CC = new ClassC();
        CC.A1 = "qwer";
        CC.B1 = "rewq";
        CA.c.Add(CC);

        ClassD CD = new ClassD();
        CD.A2 = "lkjh";
        CD.B2 = "aqws";
        return CA;
    }
```

so i am getting error at

> CA.c.Add(CC);

and the error was `"object reference not set to an instance of an object"`

whatever return ViewModel that one I going to compare with actual models, so how could I do this.

Comment: public class ClassA
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public List<ClassC> c { get; set; }
        public List<ClassD> d { get; set; }

        public ClassA()
        {
            c=new List<ClassC>();
            d=new List<ClassD>();
        }
    }

Comment: you need new instances for array

Comment: @snnbrn yes i need new instance for creating new array and thanks for help